No module named 'psycop'. Cannot make migrations
I'm trying to get a login page not to return a 500 error, and have been trying to migrate my database.
I have installed psycopg2 correctly (I believe), but I think I have not got the correct NAME in DATABASES at settings.py. Here is what I have:
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.postgresql',
}

}
Would somebody know if what I have in 'NAME' is correct, or what else I should put in there? Thank you.

Do you have psycopg2-binary package instead of psycopg2

no, I unstalled everything and only installed psycop2

You’re using a setting stanza for sqlite3, not Postgres. Read the docs.

The 'NAME' parameter 'NAME' must contain the name of the database you created in PostgreSQL, not a path to a file.
look at this article if you need more information : https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-postgresql-django

Hello, thank you. How do I know the name of the database I created?

If you’re using a GUI like pgAdmin:

Open pgAdmin and connect to your PostgreSQL server.
In the left-hand panel, expand the server tree and look under "Databases" to see all existing databases.

If not, you can do that with the psql command line. I'll let you find out more online, you should easily find the commands you need to make.
